# Appcelerator 4 cannot find Android SDK on Mac

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

Appcelerator Studio 4.7.1.201609100950 on Mac OS X cannot find Android SDK. I have downloaded it with the button on the Appcelerator Studio Dashboard. After download was successfully finished, the Appcelerator Studio was not able to recognise it. 
I was getting the following error : [Android SDK Home] No Android SDKs were found under the specified SDK location

Comment: Have you tried restarting Studio?

Comment: yes, I have tried several times to restart the studio and redownload the SDK. I have even tried to download SDK with android Studio, make sure that it is actually working and the simulator can be run, and then tried to point Titanium to this SDK, but also without any success.

Comment: You might want to look at this line of code: titanium config android.sdk /Users/appc/sdk/android-sdk/  Btw, did you look at this page: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. The reason is (for me at least) is when I first created the App, it was with an older version of Studio & SDK.

One solution, is **create a new Project** with the latest SDK & Studio, then paste all your code in that new project (make sure everything is updated correctly in tiapp.xml), then you will see there is no more issues running Android.

You can also try it with just a new Mobile Project (with latest SDK, currently 5.5.1.GA), and see if it runs on Android. If this works, you can move all your code to this new project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

To use the Android SDK with Studio, the path to the SDK must be set in the Preferences dialog.

1. Open the Preferences dialog:On Mac OS X, from the menu bar, select Appcelerator Studio > Preferences.
2. In the Preferences dialog, navigate to Studio > Platforms > Android.
3. Enter the path to your Android SDK in the [Android SDK Home] textbox by clicking Browse then navigate to the SDK directory.

The Android SDK will be found in the Library folder...something like /Users//Library/android-sdk

You did install the android-sdk right!?

Answer (score 0):

What happens from command line when you run appc ti info -t android?

Also, check your Android SDK setting in appc ti config as well as check to see if you've set an environment variable in

> /~/.bash_profile called ANDROID_SDK

, and if so that it matches the correct current location of the SDK
If you can't solve this try to change your sdk directory and change it in appcelerator too.
Hope that will help you.

Comment: I am getting the following error message  $ appc ti info -t android
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.5.1
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

 /An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
Cannot read property 'version' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I personally store my SDK and NDK in

```
/opt/android-sdk
```

and

```
/opt/android-ndk
```

with links in the `.bash_profile`

```
export ANDROID_SDK=/opt/android-sdk
export ANDROID_NDK=/opt/android-ndk
```

finally, use `appc ti setup android` to set the paths there as well. Both Studio and CLI will pick it up properly from there. Thx!